# how to sort the items in QListWidget by drop and drag

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt, qlistwidget

I am newer to pyqt, I am using it to write some GUI, could anybody please tell me how to sort the items in QListWidget by drop and drag?

thanks in advance

Comment: Reason for -1: question should clarify you using code from QtDesigner, and cull down to a short self-contained example to go from. Since so few details were specified, and no code, no details of your workflow, the answer from Gary Hughes is likely to not help you.

Answer (score 4):

`QListWidget` inherits from `QAbstractItemView`. You can use the `QAbstractItemView.setDragDropMode()` and set it to `QAbstractItemView.InternalMove` if you'd like to be able to change the order of your items with drag & drop.

[Here's the relevent section of the documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemview.html#setDragDropMode).

Here's a quick example showing it in action:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, \
    QVBoxLayout, QListWidget, QAbstractItemView

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.widget_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Create ListWidget and add 10 items to move around.
        self.list_widget = QListWidget()
        for x in range(1, 11):
            self.list_widget.addItem('Item {:02d}'.format(x))

        # Enable drag & drop ordering of items.
        self.list_widget.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)

        self.widget_layout.addWidget(self.list_widget)
        self.setLayout(self.widget_layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  widget = Widget()
  widget.show()

  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. but ... I use qt designer to set the drag and drop mode, and use pyuic4 to generate the py code, I rewrite the dropEvent dropEnterEvent and dargEvent, seems no effect. (all item are pic, and showed as icon)